# NewRelic reporting when using Rack::Timeout

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, newrelic

We're running in an environment (Heroku) in which requests longer than 30 seconds will be interrupted. Therefore our web server (Unicorn) is set to abort after 15 seconds. We have noticed that when a request is interrupted no information seems to be logged to NewRelic.

Any recommendations for how to get around this? My first thought was to use Rack::Timeout to have Rack cancel the request. Will this work with newrelic_rpm? Where in the middleware chain is newrelic injected?

We're running Ruby 1.9.3 with Sinatra.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use Rack::Timeout and let New Relic report the resulting exception as an error.

The Unicorn timeout causes the worker to be killed, which includes the New Relic reporting thread.

Comment: Sounds promising, will have a look and report back.

Comment: How did it go? (10 years later :))